# Make offer to opensea asset through opensea-js

Tags: web3js, nodejs, opensea

I'm using opensea-js alongside with nodejs to make offer on opensea testnet assets. The code is following:

```js
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

const Web3 = require('web3')
const opensea = require('opensea-js')

const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io')

const seaport = new opensea.OpenSeaPort(provider, {
  networkName: opensea.Network.Main
})

const call = async () => {
  const accountAddress = "my_metamask_wallet_address_on_rinkeby_network"
  const tokenId = 12
  const tokenAddress = "0x7dca125b1e805dc88814aed7ccc810f677d3e1db"
  const offer = await seaport.createBuyOrder({
    asset: {
      tokenAddress: tokenAddress,
      tokenId: tokenId,
    },
    accountAddress: accountAddress,
    startAmount: 1
  })
  console.log(offer.expirationTime)
}

call()
```

But it throws a 404 not found error, what am I doing wrong? The response is `{"success": false}`.

Comment: Not familiar with opensea, but seeing rinkeby testnet provider and opensea main net together seems strange.

Comment: networkName: opensea.Network.Main  is probably not Rinkeby

Comment: You might also need an infura API key afer the infura url

Comment: it doesn't work even when i change it to mainnet.infura.io

Answer (score 5):

Few things

1. You cannot use `HttpProvider` as the opensea-js library should be able to sign the transaction on your behalf.
   Try using HDWalletProvider or something similar with your mnemonic or private key to allow signing of the buy order.

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: "<your wallet mnemonic>",
    providerOrUrl: "rinkeby infura link",
    addressIndex: 1
});
```

2. You need to connect OpenSeaPort to the Rinkeby network.

```
const seaport = new opensea.OpenSeaPort(provider, {
  networkName: opensea.Network.Rinkeby
})
```

Final code should look something like

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const opensea = require('opensea-js')
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
    mnemonic: "<your wallet mnemonic>",
    providerOrUrl: "https://rinkeby.infura.io",
    addressIndex: 0
});

const seaport = new opensea.OpenSeaPort(provider, {
  networkName: opensea.Network.Rinkeby
})

const call = async () => {
  const accountAddress = "my_metamask_wallet_address_on_rinkeby_network"
  const tokenId = 12
  const tokenAddress = "0x7dca125b1e805dc88814aed7ccc810f677d3e1db"
  const offer = await seaport.createBuyOrder({
    asset: {
      tokenAddress: tokenAddress,
      tokenId: tokenId,
    },
    accountAddress: accountAddress,
    startAmount: 1
  })
  console.log(offer.expirationTime)
}

call()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

Comment: is there a reason I'm getting 404 not found error? Instead of just rinkeby.infura.io I'm putting a link from infura. thats xxxxxxxx:yyyyy/@eth2-beacon-mainnet.infura.io. Wallet address and mnemonics are correct.

Comment: Your infura link should look like the following
`https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<api key>`

Comment: what about project id? It says invalid project id

Comment: <api key> should be <project id> above. Your infura project id to be sure. @KunalJain has the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. It turns out the asset I was trying to retrieve was on Mumbai testnet, not on Rinkeby.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).